# using setTimout() as Promise in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, es6-promise

I am new to JS and I am writing some simple REST API in Node.js for my application.
Somewhere inside the code I want to wait for about 5 seconds.

I am so confused about using of Promise and normal timeout method and call the function somewhere else. as following:

```
const sleep = (time) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
            console.log('5 seconds');
        }, time);
    })
}
```

and then call the function:

```
sleep(5000)
```

OR

```
const sleep = (time) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
           resolve()
           console.log('5 seconds');
       }, time);
    })
}
```

and then call the function:

```
sleep(5000).then(() => console.log('5 seconds passed'))
```

OR

```
const sleep = (time) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
            console.log('5 seconds');
        }, time);
    })
}

async function wait(sleepTime) {
    await sleep(sleepTime)
}
```

and then call the function:

```
wait(5000)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because in all 3 cases I actually get a waiting time of 5 seconds but since the function returns Promise, I have to use `.then()` If I want to use the Promise.

Comment: Yes, you always need to use `then` or `await` to wait for the delay and defer things like `console.log('5 seconds passed')` after it. There is no difference between your snippets with respect to that.

Comment: Btw, you really should remove that `console.log('5 seconds');` line from the `sleep` function that has a parameter for dynamic sleep times.

Comment: when you have a function that returns a Promise you have to use it inside another function with 'await' to call it OR you use 'then' . But is it possible not  to use both 'await and then' and still get the answer? as it happens in 1st case.

Comment: What do you mean by "answer", and what does happen "in 1st case"? No, it's fundamentally impossible to get a result from the future immediately, you have to wait one way or another.

Comment: in these 3 cases I get the same answer.  If they are the same then why I should use '.then' after calling the function?

Comment: If by "answer" you refer to the log output, the second case should be different as it logs twice. You should use `then` because it allows you to do different things after the promise fulfilled, e.g. `sleep(5000).then(() => console.log('5 sec'))` vs `sleep(3000).then(() => console.log('3 sec'))`. If you are just looking for the advantage of using promises over plain callbacks, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

**then** you use when you want to get the result of promise, promise's code will work anyway even without using its result

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
In case 3, you can `await` an `async` function.

```
(async () => {
  await wait(5000);
  // Do something after 5 sec
})();
```

---

There is nothing wrong with your code.
So I am not sure what is your problem.

Anyway, you can understand `Promise` in this way:

```
new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
  }, 5000);
}).then(() => {
  // Do something after 5 sec 
});
```

is equivalent to

```
setTimeout(() => {
  // Do something after 5 sec
}, 5000);
```

Comment: My problem is actually about calling of a function that return Promise.

Answer (score 0):

**First case.**

1. Asynchronous Execution as `doSomething()` doesn't wait for `sleep` function to finish execution. 

2. The promise will remain in pending state.

```
sleep(5000); 
doSomething();// execution starts without waiting for 5 seconds.
```

**Second Case :** 

1.Promise is resolved the `then()/catch()` listener is called.

2. Making `doSomething()` execute after `sleep()` has finished its execution.

```
sleep(5000).then(() => {doSomething();// execution starts after waiting for 5 seconds. })
```

**Third Case :** 

1. Async function returns a promise.

2. Await/then - works in the same way (resolves/rejects a promise and return data/error).

3. Await can only be used inside async function.


I would suggest you create only one async function which contains the business logic for the api.

```
async function wait(sleepTime) {
    // some code 
    await sleep(sleepTime); // waiting  
    doSomething(); // execution starts only after waiting.
    // some other code
}
```

Calling `wait` without `then` will result in pending promise but that would not affect your business logic.

```
// sample example.
wait(5000).then(()=>{res.send("ok");}).catch(e=>{res.send("err")});
```